# Edit text enable /disable new version of android

Tags: android

Hi I am using edittext in some activity I want to disable & enable the edit text but first time it will enable edit text once i disabled the edittext again it will not allow to edit the text.I am using InputType code.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/amountET"
                android:hint="@string/amount"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType=""
                tools:ignore="Autofill,NestedWeights,TextFields" />
```

In activity using like this

```
       if (selectedCategoryTypeId.equals("5")) {
                amountET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                amountET.setFocusable(false);

            } else if (selectedCategoryTypeId.equals("14")) {
                amountET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                amountET.setFocusable(false);

            } else if (selectedCategoryTypeId.equals("20")) {
                amountET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                amountET.setFocusable(false);


            } else if (selectedCategoryTypeId.equals("6")) {
                amountET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                amountET.setFocusable(false);

            } else {
                amountET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
         InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                amountET.setFocusable(true);

            }
```

Pls help....

Comment: use `editText.setEnabled(falre or true)`

Comment: Are you looking for `amountET.setEnabled(true/false)` ?

Comment: @AntoineElMurr I used .setEnabled also still not working

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil In else part I need edit text enabled other cases i need to disable the edit text

Comment: Yeah. `amountET.setEnabled(false)` on `onCreate` and in the else part enable it. `amountET.setEnabled(true)`. Will this not work?

Comment: yes its working Thank you so much @MadhanVaradhodiyil